# Use Function in Initializer - Swift?

Tags: swift, initialization

Assume the following:

```
class A {
    let x : Int
    init() {
        self.x = assign(1)
    }
    func assign(y : Int) -> Int {
        return y
    }
}
```

This produces an error.

Here is my question : is there a way to call functions within the class initializer?

EDIT: Added error message:

> use of 'self' in method call 'assign' before all stored properties are initialized

Comment: What is the exception / error you are getting? Would be helpful to see the actual result you are getting

Comment: There are multiple solutions but a real use case would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not the greatest solution but still it is working.

```
 class A {
        var variable : Int

        init() {

            self.variable = A.assign(1)

        }

        private class func assign(y : Int) -> Int {
            return y
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Out of curiosity, why does this work while the previous method did not?

Comment: it is a class function and this kind of function do not need initialization of the object or @Sulthan could you deeply explain

Comment: I have a huge function that I would like to call from several init() methods. This huge function initializes several of the class properties. I have done as above, making this huge method a 'class' function, but I get an error on every property in the method. Of course, if I copy and paste this code into each init() method, it works.

Answer (score 4):

One other (possibly helpful) option is to have the function you call within the initializer scope:

```
class A {
    let x : Int
    init() {
        func assign(y : Int) -> Int {
            return y
        }
        self.x = assign(y: 1)
    }
}
```

I'm doing that in a project right now.  I have a *large* initializer (its actually a parser) and use an initializer-scoped function for error reporting.  Of course, I'd prefer the function to be at class scope so I can reuse it between initializers.  But at least I can reuse it within each initializer.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't call instance methods until the instance is initialized (before `init` is done), but you can use module-level functions and [*type methods*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-ID241) defined using the `class` or `static` keyword.

```
func compute(y: Int) -> Int {
  return y
}

class A {
  let x: Int

  static func assign(y: Int) -> Int {
    return y
  }

  init () {
    x = A.assign(3) + compute(4)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use somethings like:

```
class A {
    var x : Int!
    init() {
        x = assign(1)
    }
    func assign(y : Int) -> Int {
        return y
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you will get a runtime error if you access `x` and it is not initialised. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24119149/1949494) answer.

Comment: It works because now `x` is optional so the error doesn't apply anymore. Now you do not use `self` before all stored properties are initialised because you do not have such properties anymore, now they are optionals.