# Is there any way of locking an object in Swift like in C#

Tags: swift, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
func foo() {
    var sum = 0
    var pendingElements = 10

    for i in 0 ..< 10 {
        proccessElementAsync(i) { value in
            sum += value
            pendingElements--

            if pendingElements == 0 {
                println(sum)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the function `proccessElementAsync`, as its name indicates, process its input parameter asynchronously and when it finishes it calls its corresponding completion handler.

The inconvenience with this approach is that since the variable `pendingElements` is accessed through multiple threads, then it is possible that the statement `if pendingElements == 0` will never has value true.

In C# we are able to do something like:

```
Object lockObject = new Object();
...

lock (lockObject) {
    pendingElements--;

    if (pendingElements == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

and this ensures that this variable will be accessed only for a thread at the same time. Is there any way of getting the same behavior in Swift?

Comment: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-02-06-locks-thread-safety-and-swift.html

Comment: Side note: in C# `lock(someIntValue)` does not do anything remotely close to what you trying to achieve... In C# please consider following default guideline of creating special objects only for locking...

Comment: In C# we would be able to do `Interlocked.Decrement`

Comment: @Bas `Interlocked.Decrement` will not help to protect 2 variables - like `pendingElements` and `sum` as shown.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have updated the c# code, I think that I was too informal with it. Sorry for that

Comment: @ReynaldoAguilar - looks good now. In general keep in mind that it is not possible for readers to distinguish between "informal/quickly written sample" and "complete misunderstanding of a concept". So showing correctly looking code significantly improves chances of answer to actually address what you are looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
func lock(obj: AnyObject, blk:() -> ()) {
    objc_sync_enter(obj)
    blk()
    objc_sync_exit(obj)
}

var pendingElements = 10

func foo() {
    var sum = 0
    var pendingElements = 10

    for i in 0 ..< 10 {
        proccessElementAsync(i) { value in

            lock(pendingElements) {
                sum += value
                pendingElements--

                if pendingElements == 0 {
                    println(sum)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If the calls objc_sync_enter(obj) and objc_sync_exit do what I believe, then your answer solves my problem. Can you add to your answer some details about what these functions do? I think that this will improve the quality of the answer

Comment: I have got the information of objc_sync_enter and exit from Apple's document .
     
objc_sync_enter(id obj)
:
Begin synchronizing on 'obj'. Allocates recursive pthread_mutex associated with 'obj' if needed.
          

int objc_sync_exit(id obj):
End synchronizing on 'obj'.

Comment: just for others, I would suggest a more robust version `func synchronized(object:AnyObject!, @noescape _ closure: () throws -> ()) rethrows {
    objc_sync_enter(object)
    defer {
        objc_sync_exit(object)
    }
    try closure()
}`

Comment: See even more generic option in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34173952/5171225)

Comment: This is great for simple things, but if you want to do an early-return inside the lock, you can't (your return just returns from the lock scope, not from the `foo()` function. Unfortunate :-(

Answer (score 6):

There is no native locking tools, but there are workarounds like explained in this SO question:

[What is the Swift equivalent to Objective-C's "@synchronized"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045895/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-to-objective-cs-synchronized)

Using one of the answers, you can create a function:

```
    func synchronize(lockObj: AnyObject!, closure: ()->()){
        objc_sync_enter(lockObj)
        closure()
        objc_sync_exit(lockObj)
    }
```

and then:

```
     func foo() {
        var sum = 0
        var pendingElements = 10

        for i in 0 ..< 10 {
            processElementAsync(i) { value in

                synchronize(pendingElements) {
                    sum += value
                    pendingElements--

                    if pendingElements == 0 {
                        println(sum)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```