# How to avoid deadlock calling custom DispatchQueue sync from main thread?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to safely read/write data from multiple threads, like described here: [Create thread safe array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28191079/5595519)

Here's a snippet how I read data

```
    private let annotationsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myCustoLabel", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var unsafeAnnotations = [MapAnnotation]()
    private var annotations: [MapAnnotation] {
        var annotationsCopy: [MapAnnotation]!
        annotationsQueue.sync {
            annotationsCopy = self.unsafeAnnotations
        }
        return annotationsCopy
    }
```

My issue is that `annotations` is sometimes being called from `DispatchQueue.main.async`, which causes dead lock.

Here's are screenshot of stack trace, when I reach dead lock

[image]

My question is how should I handle such situation? Should I somehow force my `annotationsQueue` run on background thread?
Or I should write my code, so `annotations` are never called from `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: here you read some annotation data. right? `annotationsQueue.sync`

Comment: @JatinRB yes, I've added screenshot to highlight the issue

Comment: for some reason low priority task it will not work so please try getter setter method like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084754/objc-sync-enter-objc-sync-exit-not-working-with-dispatch-queue-priority-low

Comment: Pretty simple. Don’t use `sync`.

Comment: @JatinRB you linked a question, not answer. And it seems my implementation is the same as in some answers

Comment: @matt won't I have issues, when one thread will write and other will ready if I wont use sync?

Comment: No, async on a serial queue is a form of locking. But you won’t be able to make this a computed property.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating concurrent queue can use dispatch barrier for read/write from multiple threads.

```
 private let annotationsQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myCustoLabel", attributes: .concurrent)
   

private var unsafeAnnotations = [MapAnnotation]()

private var annotations: [MapAnnotation]? {
    var annotationsCopy: [MapAnnotation]!
    get {
      annotationsQueue.sync {
        return annotationsCopy
    }
    return nil

    }
    set {
      annotationsQueue.async(flag: .barrier) {
           annotationsCopy = self.unsafeAnnotations
       }
    }   

}
```