# Invalid update on TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi friends of StackOverflow.

I have a chat screen on my app and I it perform a insertion and deletion based on the actual size of the an Array. Look this:

```
func addObject(object: Object?) {

    if comments == nil || object == nil || object?.something == nil || object?.anything == nil {
      return
    }

    self.objectsTableView.beginUpdates()

    if self.objects!.count == 10 {
      self.objects?.removeAtIndex(9)
      self.objectsTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow : 9, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)
    }

    self.objects?.insert(object!, atIndex: 0)
    self.objectsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow : 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)

    self.objectsTableView.endUpdates()

  }
```

But after some stress test, the log notify:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I don't know whats happening, this happens only when the insert of objects is very extreme, like one per 0.2 seconds.

Someone know that I can do?

Comment: Are you updating the `self.objects` array in multiple threads?  Swift arrays are not thread safe, so you should take appropriate precautions to precent concurrent update

Comment: I'm using this: https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/845517fed6bec0fd41ff

Comment: So yes, you are.  You need to guard your updates to the array - see Matt Bridges answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045895/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-to-objective-cs-synchronized (Not the accepted answer)

Comment: Not working. Crash on 145 item of the Array.

Comment: Well, the original crash message in your question indicates that the array was empty (well, it had one item) when it was expected to have 10, so look where else you may be updating the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the guy that solved the problem: **Semaphore**

The error still happens, but only with a high size of items on list. I don't know what can be.

The DataSource protocol:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = self.objects?.count ?? 0
    if self.semaphore != nil && semaphoreCode == BLOCKED_STATE {
      dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.semaphore!)
    }
    return count
  }
```

The method that add object:

```
func addObject(object: Object?) {

    if object == nil {
      return
    }

    if self.semaphore != nil {
      let tempSemaCode = dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore!, 100000)
      if tempSemaCode == BLOCKED_STATE {
        self.semaphoreCode = RELEASED_STATE
      }
    }

    if self.objects != nil && semaphoreCode != BLOCKED_STATE {

      var needsRemoveLastItem = false
      if self.objects!.count == 10 {
        self.objects?.removeAtIndex(9)
        needsRemoveLastItem = true
      }
      self.objects?.insert(object!, atIndex: 0)

      if self.objects!.count > 0 {
        self.objectsTableView.beginUpdates()
        if needsRemoveLastItem {
          self.objectsTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow : 9, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)
        }
        self.objectsTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow : 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)
        self.objectsTableView.endUpdates()
        self.semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(BLOCKED_STATE)
      }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Model mismatch**

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted)

In plain English for the reasonable man, the `UITableView` thinks you should have 11 rows:
`10` before the update + `1` inserted.

> number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1)

...refers to  `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning `1` for section `0`, which indicates that the `objects` array is out of sync, assuming you use something like below:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}
```

---

**Use `NSFetchedResultsController`**

A clean solution is to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to be the interface between your model and the UI. It has well studied boilerplate code and is a great platform to ensure thread safety. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html).

---

**Note:**

Neat effect! The cell seems to rotate around to the top.
I could not break it using the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/845517fed6bec0fd41ff) you produced, nor scheduling multiple concurrent tests. There must be a **rogue access** to your `Object` array.

**Demo**

This simplified version works. Just hook `doPlusAction` to a button action and watch it loop:

[image: neat effect]

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var objects:[Int] = [0,1,2,3,4]
    var insertions = 5

    @IBAction func doPlusAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        objects.removeAtIndex(4)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 4, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)
        objects.insert(insertions++, atIndex: 0)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Right)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) //happens the same with this too, when reach 100-150 items
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.doPlusAction(self)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell \(objects[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I tried to add a `dispatch_semaphore_create` with a `NSBlockOperation`. Not working too.

Comment: take a look my my answer.