# Mutex alternatives in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, concurrency, mutual-exclusion

I have a shared-memory between multiple threads. I want to prevent these threads access this piece of memory at a same time. (like *producer-consumer* problem)

**Problem**:

A thread add elements to a queue and another thread reads these elements and delete them. They shouldn't access the queue simultaneously.

One solution to this problem is to use Mutex.

As I found, there is no Mutex in Swift. Is there any alternatives in Swift?

Comment: I think you can look for Grand Central Dispatch check this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1

Comment: Using `Dispatch Queue` you can solve this type of problem .

Comment: Please update your question with more specific details of what you have and what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to prevent concurrent reads or prevent writing while reading?

Comment: @rmaddy I edited my question. Yes, I want to do this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710200/thread-safety-for-a-getter-and-setter-in-a-singleton for some ideas.

Comment: You can use dispatch semaphore. Initialize with 1, and wait/signal before/after accessing the semaphore.

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that swift does have mutexes: `pthread_mutex_t`. However, these low level APIs are incredibly complex and you should think very carefully about whether you really need them. The solutions below are much better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As people commented (incl. me), there are several ways to achieve this kind of lock. But I think dispatch semaphore is better than others because it seems to have the least overhead. As found in Apples [doc, "Replacing Semaphore Code"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW14), it doesn't go down to kernel space unless the semaphore is already locked (= zero), which is the only case when the code goes down into the kernel to switch the thread. I think that semaphore is not zero most of the time (which is of course app specific matter, though). Thus, we can avoid lots of overhead.

One more comment on dispatch semaphore, which is the opposite scenario to above. If your threads have different execution priorities, and the higher priority threads have to lock the semaphore for a long time, dispatch semaphore may not be the solution. This is because there's no "queue" among waiting threads. What happens at this case is that higher priority
threads get and lock the semaphore most of the time, and lower priority threads can lock the semaphore only occasionally, thus, mostly just waiting. If this behavior is not good for your application, you have to consider dispatch queue instead.

Comment: pthread mutexes and unfair locks also support priority inversion avoidance.

Answer (score 22):

There are many solutions for this but I use serial queues for this kind of action:

```swift
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queuename")
serialQueue.sync { 
    //call some code here, I pass here a closure from a method
}
```

Edit/Update: Also for semaphores:

```swift
let higherPriority = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
let lowerPriority = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

func letUsPrint(queue: DispatchQueue, symbol: String) {
    queue.async {
        debugPrint("\(symbol) -- waiting")
        semaphore.wait()  // requesting the resource

        for i in 0...10 {
            print(symbol, i)
        }

        debugPrint("\(symbol) -- signal")
        semaphore.signal() // releasing the resource
    }
}

letUsPrint(queue: lowerPriority, symbol: "Low Priority Queue Work")
letUsPrint(queue: higherPriority, symbol: "High Priority Queue Work")

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: Let me know if my approach solves your problem or else provide me other ways, I also want to have some efficient way to solve this thing

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to [beshio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4599632/beshio)'s comment, you can use semaphore like this:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
```

use wait before using the resource:

```
semaphore.wait()
// use the resource
```

and after using release it:

```
semaphore.signal()
```

Do this in each thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSLock or NSRecursiveLock. If you need to call one locking function from another locking function use recursive version.

```
class X {
  let lock = NSLock()

  func doSome() {
    lock.lock()
    defer { lock.unlock() }
    //do something here
  }

}
```

Comment: If you need to call one locking function from another, I would recommend first stopping to think why you need to do that, and perhaps restructuring your code so you don't need. Recursive mutexes add overhead and are generally an excellent way to create intractable code.

Comment: Agree, All "mutex like" code can be replaced with serial queue that is better solution anyway. I would argue that mutexes and similar sync primitives should not ever be exposed to swift app programmer anyway. Now we have async/await/tasks ..we just need to move on.

Answer (score 1):

On modern platforms (macOS 10.12+, iOS 10+) [`os_unfair_lock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_unfair_lock) is a performant, efficient general-purpose mutex, especially if your critical section is short. It's much more lightweight (30x smaller) than a queue and tracks priority, preventing inversions that can occur with a `DispatchSemaphore`.

As with most low-level synchronization primitives, it needs to have a stable address, so you should either allocate it yourself, or you can use [`OSAllocatedUnfairLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/osallocatedunfairlock) if available on newer (macOS 13+, iOS 16+) systems. If these aren't an option for you or you're not very comfortable with working with the lock directly, [`NSLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslock) adds a small amount of overhead but is not a bad alternative. Especially when compared to a queue or semaphore :)