# Implementation of swift's synchronized not working

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency

I am new to swift and I am trying my hands with multithreading, a concept which doesn't seem to be famous in swift. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679563/1941002) example of java's `synchronized`implementation I tried to do the same for swift based on examples given for swift on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24103086/1941002) SO post. Here is my implementation:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

public class TestThread {
    var name : String;
    var theDemo : TheDemo;
    init(_ name : String, _ theDemo : TheDemo) {
        self.theDemo = theDemo;
        self.name = name;
        run()
    }

    public func run() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.theDemo.testSynced(self.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TheDemo {
    private func synced(_ lock : Any, _ name : String, _ closure : (_ name : String) -> ()){
        objc_sync_enter(lock)
        defer { objc_sync_exit(lock) }
        closure(name)

    }
    public func testSynced(_ name : String){
        synced(self, name, test)
    }
    public func test(_ name : String) {
        for i in 0..<4 {
            let str = "\(name) :: \(i)"
            let theDeadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(i/2)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: theDeadline, execute: {
                print(str)
            })
        }
    }

}

var theDemo = TheDemo()
TestThread("THREAD 1", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 2", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 3", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 4", theDemo)
```

When I run the above code in the playground the result I get looks like the following

```
THREAD 1 :: 0
THREAD 1 :: 1
THREAD 2 :: 0
THREAD 2 :: 1
THREAD 3 :: 0
THREAD 3 :: 1
THREAD 4 :: 0
THREAD 4 :: 1
THREAD 1 :: 2
THREAD 1 :: 3
THREAD 2 :: 2
THREAD 2 :: 3
THREAD 3 :: 2
THREAD 3 :: 3
THREAD 4 :: 2
THREAD 4 :: 3
```

But I was expecting a result that looks like the following.

```
THREAD 1 :: 0
THREAD 1 :: 1
THREAD 1 :: 2
THREAD 1 :: 3
THREAD 2 :: 0
THREAD 2 :: 1
THREAD 2 :: 2
THREAD 2 :: 3
THREAD 3 :: 0
THREAD 3 :: 1
THREAD 3 :: 2
THREAD 3 :: 3
THREAD 4 :: 0
THREAD 4 :: 1
THREAD 4 :: 2
THREAD 4 :: 3
```

I wish to understand what I am doing wrong. Have I set my expectation also on the right path considering the concept of synchronisation and swift threads. I appreciate the help. thanks.

**EDIT**

Since I believe that I am misunderstood, I want to explain a bit more of what I want to do. What I basically want to achieve is a bit different than what I have written here in the code. This is a simplified version. I want to test it if `synchronized` works in a simple example and then I want to use it in another project. I am translating a project written for android to ios. In java multithreading I am using `synchronized` so that only one thread at a time can use that function. let's say there is a variable or a function that multiple threads can work on. When I put synchronized before the function name or the variable name, threads will have a lock. Now in my project I have several threads, that come and go, based on some sensor input - and before they die they make use of a common shared function. They could come at any point. For several reasons, we set that common function `synchronized` so that no two threads enter the function at the same time. Thus, when I am translating the code I looked for what would be similar in swift and I found one of the links that is linked to this question. And I tried to use that - and it didn't work for me. To err is human - and I probably have made a mistake somewhere. But I have spent time to read based on the schedule I have. (I partly said that multithreading isn't very famous in swift because of some places I have read for example [this](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html))

Comment: Please search on "asynchronous". This has been explained here _many many many_ times.

Comment: My question was rather on the keyword synchronized and the expected output. I implemented based on the suggestions I found in stackoverflow and the result doesn't resemble that of java's. Can you please not downvote me - I d rather delete the question. Thanks.

Comment: "I d rather delete the question" Then delete it.

Comment: I have tried to include some more description. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: “For several reasons, we set that common function synchronized so that no two threads enter the function at the same time.” Fine. So see my answer: in Cocoa and GCD, we use serial queues to accomplish the same thing. Serial queues are a form of locking — a better form.

Comment: Hi @matt I want to say thanks. I was able to synchronize resource access by using serial queues. So, in my application I made use of both serial and concurrent queues. But I don't understand why there is that stackoverflow post that confused me (about the synchronized keyword that i included.) I wonder if I should delete this question or leave it as it is and accept your answer.

Comment: Well I wish you’d do one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, never test these things in a playground, as its output will not correctly simulate reality. Test in an actual app project.

Second, get rid of all this:

```
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(lock) }
    closure(name)
```

Do whatever it is you want done purely using GCD.

I'm not clear on what you do want done; the kerfuffle with `objc_sync_enter` and `asyncAfter` is just too mystifying for me. This stuff, however, is not at all mystifying, and is very well documented and explained (contrary to your claim).

From your desired output, it looks like you want to queue the "thread 1" operation and have it run from start to finish before the "thread 2" operation starts.

- One way to guarantee that is to queue these operations onto a *serial queue*, because that means that a queued operation cannot start until the queue ahead of it is empty. That's not happening in your code because you queue is a *concurrent* queue, meaning that the operations run *at the same time* (i.e. their steps can be interleaved with one another).
- Another way would be to call the "thread 1" operation with `sync` rather than `async`, because that means your code waits (blocks) until the operation completes and returns.

Here's an example of the first way, which I think is the better way:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue") // serial queue
func go() {
    for i in 0..<4 {
        let name = "Thread \(i)"
        queue.async {
            for i in 0..<4 {
                let str = "\(name) :: \(i)"
                print(str)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output when we call `go()`:

```
Thread 0 :: 0
Thread 0 :: 1
Thread 0 :: 2
Thread 0 :: 3
Thread 1 :: 0
Thread 1 :: 1
Thread 1 :: 2
Thread 1 :: 3
Thread 2 :: 0
Thread 2 :: 1
Thread 2 :: 2
Thread 2 :: 3
Thread 3 :: 0
Thread 3 :: 1
Thread 3 :: 2
Thread 3 :: 3
```

That looks a lot like what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

### **Problem**

In `TheDemo`

```
let theDeadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(i/2)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: theDeadline, execute: {
    self.theDemo.testSynced(self.name)
```

### **Solution**

In `TestThread`:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let theDeadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: theDeadline, execute: {
```

In `TheDemo`

```
for i in 0..<4 {
    let str = "\(name) :: \(i)"
    print(str)
}
```

### **Explanation**

So.  Each asynchronous task is completing so fast that they are getting deferred to the same time from now.  You are getting an insight into how DispatchQueue's main thread handles the situation when you've asynced everything to the same time.

```
//Starts at some exact time

TestThread("THREAD 1", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 2", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 3", theDemo)
TestThread("THREAD 4", theDemo)

//Finishes at the same exact time.  Too fast!
//
```

In my solution, the printing is in a single time context (the playground's main queue where you create all your custom threads).  So it prints as you expect.  You'll have to use a much finer unit (there isn't [nanoseconds]) or design it slightly differently like I showed you.

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately, the deferring is there for a reason. I mean.. in the java example I provided they give Thread.sleep(500ms). This is so that the threads will mix when the other threads are taking long time. (if the deferring isn't there - eventhough there is multithreading - they would most probably perform sequentially.) The deferring is important to force so that the threads mix. Then, when synchronized keyword is given - they will just wait eventhough there was enough time for concurrent execution. do you get my point?

Comment: @besabestin You just have to move when you defer it, see my edited answer.  Sorry I didn't make that clear at first.

Comment: @besabestin If you think about it from an object design concern standpoint, the `TestThread` should have control over when it defers an asynchronous run to, not `TheDemo` because `TestThread` is in charge of time in it's own personal universe (the background thread).